# How are integers serialized in Tezos?

Tags: pack, serialization

I think that the  `int`, `tez` and `nat` are all serialized the same way. But what is the algorithm?

I tried running some examples through the LIGO CLI but couldn't figure out the system

```
$ ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack(1n)'
0x050001
```

`0001` is 1 in dec.

```
$ ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack(1000000n)'
0x050080897a
```

`080897a` is 8.423.802 in dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `05` prefix indicates that this serialization comes from the `PACK` assembly instruction, and the next byte `00` in case of integers (`nat`, `int`, and `tez`) indicates that the type is integer. So the numbers are represented by the bytes

- `01` for `1n`
- `80897a` for `1000000n` (1 million)

Reading each byte from left to right, the 1st indicates whether more bytes are coming. The 2nd bit of the first byte indicates if the number is positive or negative, 1 indicates negative, and 0 positive.

**`1n`:**

`01` `0x01 = 0b00000001`, 1st bit is 0, and 2nd bit is zero indicating that no more bytes are coming and that this is a positive number. The remaining six bits give the value: `0b000001 = 0x01 = 1`.

**`1000000n`:**
`80897a` = `0x80897a = 0b10000000,0b10001001,0b01111010`

The first bit in each byte indicates that this value is represented by three bytes. The 2nd bit in the 1st byte indicates that this is a positive number. The remaining bits are then `0b000000, 0b0001001, 0b1111010`. Reversing the byte order (because little-endian) we get: `0b11110100001001000000` = `0xf4240` = `1000000`

From the documentation we get:

> A variable length sequence of bytes, encoding a Zarith number. Each
> byte has a running unary size bit: the most significant bit of each
> byte tells is this is the last byte in the sequence (0) or if there is
> more to read (1). The second most significant bit of the first byte is
> reserved for the sign (positive if zero). Size and sign bits ignored,
> data is then the binary representation of the absolute value of the
> number in little endian order.

The documentation for this can be found by running `tezos-codec describe alpha.script.expr binary schema` For output at the time of reading, see: [gist.github.com/smondet/f5b785a6bbe6adb431fd7bca5e6df91a](http://gist.github.com/smondet/f5b785a6bbe6adb431fd7bca5e6df91a)