# How are sets serialized in Tezos?

Tags: serialization, pack, order

The mathematical structure of a set is an unordered collection. If a set does not have an order, how are they serialized by the `PACK` instruction?

According to [this overview](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#types) `set` **is** packable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are serialized by first ordering the elements, and then packing them as a sequence which is also how lists are represented when `PACK` is called. This means that these two expressions evaluate to the same, since they are first sorted, and then serialized.

```
ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack(set [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ])'
ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack(set [ 4; 2; 3; 1 ])'
```

Both output the same byte array

```
0x0502000000080001000200030004
```

Where

- `05` is the prefix for any output from the `PACK` instruction
- `02` is the tag for the sequence type
- `00000008` is the four bytes indicating the size of the coming values, in bytes
- `0001000200030004` are then numbers `1,2,3,4` encoded with first a `00` tag to indicate that this is a integer, and the numbers `01`, ... `04` are the encoding of the actual numbers.

Comment: Note also, that in Michelson (may be different in Ligo), concrete sets must always be ordered. That is, `PUSH (set nat) { 1 ; 3 ; 2 };` does not typecheck, where as `PUSH (set nat) { 1 ; 2 ; 3 };` does.

Comment: For more details on how integers are encoded: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2882/5135

Comment: Each datatype that is `Comparable` has an order. The ordering of integers is there numerical order, the ordering of strings **and** addresses is alphabetical ordering. Cf https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#instr-COMPARE